# Finding string in a HashMap in search

Tags: java, android

I am implementing search for list. I am comparing data with the array list that contains `HashMap`s. How do I get a `String` out of it?

Here is my code...

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> CList;

etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable theWatchedText) {

                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> type_name_filter = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                String text = theWatchedText.toString();

                for (int i = 0; i < CList.size(); i++) {

                    if (CList.get(i)).containsKey(text.toLowerCase())) {

                        type_name_filter.add(CList.get(i));

                    }
                }

                listUpdate(type_name_filter);
            }
        });
```

My Clist Values are

```
String value1 = c.getString("Value1");
                        String userid = c.getString("UserId");
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        map.put(TAG_Value, value1);
                        map.put(TAG_UserID, userid);
                        CList.add(map);
```

Comment: show me the arraylist values......

Comment: @Jack pls check my code in TAG_Value i am gettin values like hotel, Car, Bikes

Comment: Add the error you are getting to complete your question.It will help others

Comment: I am not getting any error but i am getting 0 Value in type_name_filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) has no function `contains`. The HashMap only has methods `containsKey()` or `containsValue()`

Change:

```
if ((CList.get(i)).contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
```

To:

```
if ((CList.get(i)).containsKey(text.toLowerCase())) {
```

Comment: if ((CategoryList.get(i).toLowerCase()).containsKey(text.toLowerCase())) for this condotion i am getting error.

Comment: @Simon no Map do not have a method `toLowerCase`. You have to store your keys in lower case.

Comment: i am not getting error now but i am not getting any values. It is showing zero in type_name_filter. Please cau check the updated code and can u edit it

Comment: if ((CategoryList.get(i).get("Value")).contains(text.toLowerCase())) {

      type_name_filter.add(CategoryList.get(i));

     } it is not maching the value, in type_name_filter i am getting nothing it is showing null

Comment: Yes Jens i am using debugger

Comment: Hey i am getting ans..but it is matching exact value ex: If Food = Food it will give the ans. But If i given food it is not displaying Food. Can u suggest me

Comment: @Simon Put the keys iin lower case in your map.